# How to add copy button wherever code tags appear in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

**I have used django-pagedown package to create markdown editor.**

After adding content using markdown editor.
while getting data from models, I want to add a copy button to the right corner or inside to the code tags just like StackOverflow to copy the code after clicking the copy button.

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    question_body = forms.CharField(widget=PagedownWidget())

    class Meta:
        """Meta definition for Questionform."""

        model = models.Question
        fields = ("question_title", "question_body")
```

```
<div class="p-2 flex-grow-1" id="anSWER{{ forloop.counter }}">
  <p>{{ answer.answer_text|markdown }}</p>
</div>
<div class="p-2 ml-auto">
<button">Copytext</button>
</div>
```